# Error #2044: Unhandled ioError:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: file:///C|/xampp/htdocs/flash/apm01.php at as3_fla::MainTimeline/checkComplete()

Tags: actionscript

I have a function in my AS3 that frequently calls a PHP file. It fails and throws the error I used in the title. I always get this error message. But when I run it in a browser it works fine. I don't know what seems to be the problem.This is my code:

```
    $function checkComplete(evt:MouseEvent):void {

    // Create A new URLVariables instance to store the variable
    var myVariables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();

    // Create a variable (e.g. username) to send
    myVariables.username = candidate_txt.text;

// Create a new URLRequest instance sending data to "ascom01.php"
var myRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("apm01.php");

// Send data using the POST method
myRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

// The data property of the request is set to the
// URLVariables instance (myVariables) to send to the PHP file.
// Note: myVariables stored the variable (e.g. candidate)
myRequest.data = myVariables;

// Create a new instance of the URLLoader class to work with.
// URLLoader.load( ) method should be used when we need the 
// sent variables returned back to Flash ActionScript.
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader;

//specify dataFormat property of the URLLoader to be "VARIABLES"
//This ensure that the variables loaded into Flash with the same variable names
myLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;

//Load the PHP file by using URLRequest
myLoader.load(myRequest);

//Listen when the loading of data COMPLETE
//Call the loadComplete function when the loading COMPLETE
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete);

}

// Hook up the button with the function checkComplete
enter_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkComplete);

// This is the function that display the data returned back from PHP file
function loadComplete(evt:Event):void {

//Display the value with variable name "totalItem"
total_txt.text = evt.target.data.totalItem

//Get the value (string) with variable name "phpConfirm"
var myResult:String = evt.target.data.phpConfirm;

//Split the string into an Array
var myArray:Array = myResult.split("|");
//output_txt.text = "The number of items are: " + myArray.length;

var finalString = "";
var i:int;
for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {

finalString = finalString + myArray[i] + "<br>";
    }

    output_txt.htmlText = finalString;


    }`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exception arises because you have to deploy your php files into the php-server. Flash couldn't run php code. You trying to launch it from disk C.

So

```
var myRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("apm01.php");
```

should be something like

```
var myRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://myhost:80/example/apm01.php");
```

Other way, you could upload your flash file to the same folder on server, and launch it from there.

Comment: I have done what you've suggested but it just returns the same error.

Error opening URL 'http://localhost/apm01.php'
Error #2044: Unhandled ioError:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: http://localhost/apm01.php
 at as3_fla::MainTimeline/checkComplete()

i have already turn my server on. It works fine when i open it on a web browser but when i run the .swf file it just returns the error abve.

Comment: By the way, getting data from another domains is not allowed by flash by default. You could create crossdomain.xml in the root of your localhost with following content: <cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-access-from domain="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>. It means that flash could load data of localhost from any domains. Another way - upload your swf to localhost and run it from there. This is not relevant for Adobe Air but important for Flash. The reason is security.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was probably an obvious one to others on this board... but I was clueless about this:

The PHP file that I was linking to from my Flash file was a new file I created on my server. It had the standard 666 permissions. Once I set the permissions to 644, everything worked beautifully.